# Can someone explain why this is checkmate for white? Can a king put another king into checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, check, kings

[image]

I am just learning to play chess so bear with me please :). I understand that the black king cannot move to d8 or f8 because of the white rook, nor d7 or f8 because of the white bishop. But why can it not move to e7 because of the white king? I though kings could not put each other into check? Thanks!

Comment: They cannot put each other in check _because they are not allowed to move next to each other_.

Comment: A checkmate requires two things: that the space the King *currently* is in is attacked, and that all spaces that the King *could* otherwise move to are also attacked. The other player's King cannot perform the first task, but it can perform the second.